# How to refer to $container-max-widths in Bootstrap

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I am currently working with Bootstrap 4 and I've made some changes to breakpoints - it looks like that:

```
$container-max-widths: (
    xs: 540px,
    sm: 700px,
    md: 960px,
    lg: 1140px,
    xl: 1300px,
    g: 1560px,
    xg: 1920px
) !default;
```

Here's my question: how can I refer to **$container-max-widths -> g** to get 1560px out of it?

I'd like to do something like this, but it's not working:

```
max-width: $grid-breakpoints('g');
```

Any ideas if that's possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a function to retrieve the breakpoint values like so:

```
@function get-breakpoints($key: "md") {
    @return map-get($container-max-widths, $key);
}

.test-class {
    max-width: get-breakpoints("g");
}
```

Comment: new bettee solution is when you use inbuilt map-get function instead writing your own

Answer (score 13):

It's possible.

```
max-width: map-get($container-max-widths, "g");
```

Comment: New best/simplest solution.

Comment: agree and upvoted this, cause don't need to write your own function, map-get is inbuilt in sass

Answer (score 6):

Import the following into your bootstrap files css/scss folder

- scss/_functions.scss
- scss/_variables.scss
- scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss

Then add the new breakpoints and container widths into your scss file

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
);
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 940px,
  xl: 1000px
);
@mixin make-max-widths-container-width($max-widths: $container-max-
widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
        max-width: $container-max-width;
    }
  }
}
.container{
   @include make-max-widths-container-width();
}
```

So it creates a new set of widths which overrides the bootstrap width.

Comment: Ho do we calculate the max-width? Why is max-width 540 for 576, or 940 for 992? What is the math? Is it the 15px padding or something?

Comment: Import order matters here! functions first, then vars.

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass in the bootstrap mixin. If you set up the boostrap overrides to come before the actual import of bootstra-grid, then the override sass-map from above will replace the "default!" sass-map properties from the bootstrap variables file.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that seemed to work, Bootstrap v.5, might not be the optimal way since using @extend

```
.your-container {
  @include make-container();
  @extend .container;
}
```