# Bootstrap 4: How to build a flexible container width such as container-sm-10 with SCSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, css-selectors, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

**In my daily work I use multiple bootstrap containers on one page. I need a flexible container width for each one.**

Bootstrap will solve this need like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
      My content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this blows up my markup and makes templating in my CMS a little hard.

**I am looking for a shorthand such as container-md-10 with the same result as above:**

```
<div class="container-sm-12 container-md-10">
  My content
</div>
```

In case of default bootstrap values with 12 grid columns .container for md is

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
    max-width:720px
  }
}
```

an my desired .container-md-10 would be

```
@media (min-width: 720px){
  .container-md-10{
    max-width:600px
  }
}
```

The Bootstrap 4 reference for a custom resposive markup with SCSS is

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#responsive

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

    .text#{$infix}-left   { text-align: left !important; }
    .text#{$infix}-right  { text-align: right !important; }
    .text#{$infix}-center { text-align: center !important; }
  }
}
```

This results e.g. in

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .text-md-left{
    text-align:left !important
  }
}
```

According to this post you can build your own container like this

[How to refer to $container-max-widths in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473690/how-to-refer-to-container-max-widths-in-bootstrap#answer-48527449)

```
@mixin make-max-widths-container-width($max-widths: $container-max-
widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
        max-width: $container-max-width;
    }
  }
}
.container{
   @include make-max-widths-container-width();
}
```

**So how can I work with these references to build my own responsive container class system with SCSS as described above?**

This is definetely possible but is beyond my SCSS capability in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 2):

I found this can work, Bootstrap v.5

Option 1

```
@mixin default-max-widths($max-widths: $container-max-widths, 
  $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
      max-width: $container-max-width;
    }  
  }
}

.my-container {
  @include make-container();
  @include default-max-widths();

}
```

Option 2

```
.my-container {
  @include make-container();
  @extend .container;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way how to achieve this:

```
@for $i from 1 through ($grid-columns) {
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max in $container-max-widths {
    $container-max: ($container-max/1px)*$i/$grid-columns;
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
        $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);
        .container-#{$i} { max-width: #{$container-max}px; }      
    }
  }
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max in $container-max-widths {
    $container-max: ($container-max/1px)*$i/$grid-columns;
    @include media-breakpoint-only($breakpoint) {
        $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);
        .container#{$infix}-#{$i} { max-width: #{$container-max}px; }      
    }
  }
}
```